# Customer Address in Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1.3, customer-address

I would like to display only one country in Customer Address(See below image). How can I do that ?

[image]

Comment: Thanks @SHPatel for your reply. I need that also in Checkout Page. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go to `Stores > Configuration > General > General` and under `Allow Countries` you should select the desired country / countries.

[image]